# Calculate valueAxix min automatically

Tags: javascript, amcharts

For LineChart

if you have series like these

```
Line1 
min 0 max 100
```

it adjust scale automatically and shows the appropriate valueAxis(ex 0 - about 110)

However like this chart

```
Line2 
min 90 max 110
```

it also change valueAxis scale (ex 0 - about 120)

However I would like to set scale like (ex 80 - about 120)

I think default amchart4 line chart calculate max of scale not min.

Can I let the amchart4 calculate min scale for value????

Comment: Can you specify what you mean? By min/max you mean the minimum and maximum values of the actual data provided to the series? Or the series' min/max properties?  When you say scale, do you mean only show values between 80 and 120 and hide the rest? What do you mean calculate min scale, doesn't it already do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `amchart4` is automatically calculating the min and max for you:

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/t09apqdf/

[image]

Here the data range is between 55 to 102. `amchart4` automatically adjusts the y axis to be between 50 to 110, which is pretty smart already!

If you have to adjust the min and max manually, use `extraMin` and `extraMax` property from `ValueAxis`:https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/valueaxis/#extraMin_property

For example, if your data is range from 90 to 110 and you want the y axis to be from 80 to 120:

```
...
// (90-80)/90 = 1/9 = 11.1%
// (120-110)/110 = 1/11 = 9.1%
"yAxes": [{
    "type": "ValueAxis",
    "extraMax": .091,
    "extraMin": .111
}],
...
```

[image]

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/hqxvpefn/

(Note: my data is generated randomly so it's hard for me to generate the extra range you're looking for. Please take a look at the fiddle links for the setup instead)

Comment: THank you for your explanation, as you told. min is automatically calculated. However in my case, there are  `series1 (0-200)` , `series 2(1000-1200)` . scale starts with 0-1200 + α、However if I hide `Series 1` by clicking label. Scale keeps  0-1200 +α , if I hide `Series 2` by clicking label , scale shrinks to 0-200+α . I think I should make sample later.

Comment: @whitebear were you able to come up with a solution? If not, please take a look at my comment to your question, and if you can make a sample that'd help, too.